# Closing eyes during somersaults

Tags: training, trampolining

I do [trampolining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampolining) and my problem is that I tend to close eyes during somersaults. It's not that I would fear highs (although I'm not very comfortable there) but I guess it's a bad habit I developed in other sport activities like while doing sit-ups or chin-ups. It comes to me as a some form of help when I can do no more - you know, tense whole body, clench teeth and close eyes. I hope I'm not the only one doing this.

It's not much of a problem in case of basic somersaults becase I can feel and guess my position easily and open eyes in time for landing. However, in double somersaults, I get lost. Maybe it's just because I have not jumped so much of them yet and I could develop the orientation in some time, but still, it's a disadvantage.

How would you overcome this obstacle?

*Note: In case you are not familiar with trampolining - it's not about doing one "uber" combo and land to a foam pit. One needs to jump ten different skills in a row.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do, not necessarily what will work for you, would be to practice keeping your eyes open for the single somersault, until you get comfortable with that and figure out what works for you. During your take off you should look forward and focus on one point that catches your eyes so that you know when to kick out. So I would continue to practice this until you find out what works for you during the single somersaults, and then once you have figured out how to keep your eyes open for that, I would then advance to the double somersaults and try the same technique that was used to work for the single somersault. This may take a lot of time, and may be a little frustrating at times as it sounds as you have developed performing them with closed eyes as a habit, but having opened eyes definitely makes the double much easier (at least for me).

Comment: Seems reasonable. I can't think of anything better than returning back to basics.